# Spring @PathVariable Map

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I can get a map of all query params like so:

```
String example(@RequestParam Map<String, String> queryParams)
```

Is there a way to get a map of all the path variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this should work:

```
String example(@PathVariable Map<String, String> pathVariables)
```

see http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/PathVariableMapMethodArgumentResolver.html

Comment: But I got error: Could not find '@PathVariable' [pathVariables] in '@RequestMapping'. Do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19803731/spring-mvc-pathvariable)

> www.mydomain.com/order/123 --> URL
>
> /order/{orderId} --> You want to fetch orderId
>
> @RequestMapping(value = " /order/{orderId}",
>   method=RequestMethod.GET) public String getOrder(@PathVariable String
>   orderId){ //fetch order }

Also there is simple example [here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-rest-hello-world-example/), Hope that helps

Thanks