# Cannot handle request by requestMapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations

I need to handle requests like

```
www.example.com/student/thisisname?age=23&country=UK&city=London
```

I am just interested in `thisisname` part and value of `city` parameter.

I have following RequestMapping but it does not work. I tried `{name}{.*:city}` as well.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{name:.*}{city}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

Comment: `city=London` is a query parameter. Use a `@RequestParam` annotated method parameter.

Comment: You can go for @PathVariable, have a look at this URL
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19803731/spring-mvc-pathvariable

Comment: Use `@PathVariable` annotated method parameter. Whenever you are passing parameter in the URL with GET method, use @PathVariable annotation to get it

Comment: Are you sure it makes sense to have a student's name as a path variable? Wouldn't a student ID work better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by 2 ways. Either using @RequestParam or @PathVariable

> 1. By Using @RequestParam

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/name", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void someMethod(@RequestParam String city){}
```

> 2. By using @PathVariable

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/name/{city}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void someMethod(@PathVariable String city){}
```

You can use any of this method just you need to concentrate on URL

Answer (score 1):

You can handle it using PathVariable and RequestParam annotation. In below code name is thisisname  part and city is query param city value.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/student/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void someMethod(@PathVariable String name, @RequestParam("city") String city){

}
```

Comment: the code returns QueryParam cannot be resolved to a 
 type

Comment: @DanielNewtown you have to add jsr311-api dependency to get QueryParam

Comment: `@QueryParam` is a JAX-RS annotation. They are using Spring MVC, which does not provide an implementation for JAX-RS.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis actually you can use spring-mvc and JAX-RS together. Anyway I have edited my answer and replaced QueryParam with RequestParam

Comment: No, you can use Spring with JAX-RS. Spring MVC is its own stack.

Comment: Hi, ```@RequestParam looks for params in your url e.g. www.exampl.com/student?name=myname. Where name id the param id and myname is the value of the param. @PathVariable will look for a variable in you url path e.g www.exampl.com/student/mname where myname is the value in the path. In you controller @Pathvariable woul be accessed like this @GetMapping(value="student/{name}"). Then you passt it in your method like this public Student getStudent(@Pathvariable("name") String studentName). For @RequestParam, they will be picked as long as they exist in you request url.```