# How can I inject @PathVariable into a field?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

Let's say I have following controller.

```
@RestController()
@RequestMapping("/my/{path}")
public class MyController {

    public void some1(@PathVariable("path") String path) {
    }

    public void some2(@PathVariable("path") String path) {
    }

    public void some3(@PathVariable("path") String path) {
    }
}
```

Now I want the `path` be injected into a field.

```
// I usually do this with JAX-RS 
@RequestScope // I added this!
@RestController()
@RequestMapping("/my/{path}")
public class MyController {

    public void some1() {
    }

    public void some2() {
    }

    public void some3() {
    }

    // single declaration for all methods
    // I know ElementType.FIELD is not one of @PathVariable's target
    // Is there any equivalent way to do this with Spring?
    @PathVariable("path")
    String path
}
```

Not compiles.

How can I do this?

Comment: No, `@PathVariable` can not do that, why do you want do this?

Comment: What is the purpose?

Answer (score -1):

request url : /a/b/c

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/a/{some}/c")
public void some(@PathVariable("some") String some) {
}
```

Answer (score -2):

@PathVariable Annotation which indicates that a method parameter should be bound to a URI template variable.

Examples :

```js
@ResponseBody
RequestMapping(value="/myapp/{id}")
public String method(@PathVariable("id") int id){
 return "id="+id;
}
 

@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value="/myapp/{id:[\\d]+}/{name}")
public String method(@PathVariable("id") long id, @PathVariable("name") String name){
 return "id= "+id+" and name="+name;
}
```

Refer more for below links :

[Spring mvc @PathVariable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19803731/spring-mvc-pathvariable)

https://www.journaldev.com/3358/spring-requestmapping-requestparam-pathvariable-example