# Spring controller test fails with 404 when @PathVariable is a string

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mockito

I am trying to test a Spring controller method - the method is at the end of the post and the test class below that. I've stripped it back a bit to try and narrow down the problem.

When I run the test as is it fails:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Status 
Expected :200
Actual   :404
```

If I edit the mockMvc.perform as follows then the test passes, I don't even have to change the @PathVariables in the controller to be Longs:

```
mockMvc.perform(get(ApplicationEndPoints.GET_CCS_NAME_AND_ADDRESS_AJAX, 1L, 2L))
       .andExpect(status().isOk());
```

The controller method itself works fine and returns JSON as expected. Can I just use these Long values and expect the test to be ok or  how can I get it to work with Strings?

I should add that I'm a total testing noob. Thanks!

controller method:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('auditor')")
@RequestMapping(value = ApplicationEndPoints.GET_APPLICANT_DATA, method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public ApplicantData getNameAndAddress(@PathVariable("businessId") String businessId, @PathVariable("date") String date) {
    //Date d = Date.valueOf(date);
    ApplicantParams params = new ApplicantParams();
    //params.setBusinessId(businessId);
    //params.setApplicationReceivedDate(d);
    params.setRoleId(ADDRESS_ROLE.HR.getRoleId());
    return applicantService.getApplicantData(params);
 }
```

test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {ApplicationTestConfig.class})
@WebAppConfiguration
public class ClientDetailAjaxControllerTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private ClientDetailAjaxController clientDetailAjaxController;
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    private ApplicantServiceInterface<Applicant> applicantService = Mockito.mock(ApplicantServiceImpl.class, Mockito.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(clientDetailAjaxController).build();
    }


    @Test
    public void getNameAndAddress() throws Exception { 
        Mockito.when(applicantService.getApplicantData(Mockito.any(ApplicantParams.class)))
               .thenReturn(ApplicationTestData.getApplicantData());
        mockMvc.perform(get(ApplicationEndPoints.GET_APPLICANT_DATA, Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString()))
               .andExpect(status().isOk());
        Mockito.verify(applicantService, Mockito.times(1)).getApplicantData(Mockito.any(ApplicantParams.class));
        Mockito.verifyNoMoreInteractions(applicantService);
    }

}
```

EDIT: I have cleared up one or two things in response to comments...

Comment: check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19803731/spring-mvc-pathvariable

Comment: also this : https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates

Answer (score 5, accepted):

404 tells you that mockMVC cannot match the controller method you're trying to call.

I'm noticing that in your controller, the path is `ApplicationEndPoints.GET_APPLICANT_DATA`, while in the test you've shown the path is `ApplicationEndPoints.GET_CCS_NAME_AND_ADDRESS_AJAX`.

Nevertheless - don't use `Mockito.anyString()` in place of parameter values you have to supply to your `RequestBuilder` in the mockMVC `perform` method.

Here's an idea how code should look like (derived from your example):

To test this controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/applicant/name-and-address/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ApplicantData getNameAndAddress(@PathVariable("businessId") String businessId, @PathVariable("date") String date) {
    // some code
 }
```

You need to do something like:

```
mockMvc.perform(get("/applicant/name-and-address/{businessId}/{date}", "myBusinessId", "myDateAsString")).andExpect(status().isOk());
```

The difference is that you have to pass actual string values, not Mockito.anyString().

Some other notes:

- If your URL path variable has the same name as the parameter you're binding it to, you can write `@PathVariable String id`, instead of `@PathVariable("id") String id`.
- you can use `@GetMapping` in place of `@RequestMapping` for `GET` method, `@PostMapping` for `POST` etc.